# Firefox addon SDK - attaching a stylesheet to a tab triggering an error

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to add a content script to a tab when the tab loads, but my code is throwing

`TypeError: window.QueryInterface is not a function'`

when I run the attachTo method.

```
var attachTo = require('sdk/content/mod').attachTo;
var style = require('sdk/stylesheet/style');

tabs.on('ready', function(tab) {
    var worker = tab.attach({
        contentScriptFile: ['./content.js']
    });
    var s = style.Style({
        uri: './style.css'
    });
    attachTo(s, tabs.activeTab.window); <------------ causes the error
    array.add(pageWorkers, worker);
    mainListener(worker);
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message suggests that `attachTo` expects an XPCOM object. `activeTab.window` returns a wrapper object around the native window. The high level APIs of the sdk generally deal in javascript wrapper objects that hide most of the internals.

You can use [`modelFor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/windows#Converting_to_chrome_windows) and [`viewFor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/windows#Converting_to_chrome_windows) to convert between those.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This was driving me insane.